# BadParcelableException: Launcher shortcut

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bundle, parcel

I'm trying to pass in a custom `Object` into a shortcut I'm installing on the home screen, but I'm receiving a `BadParcelableException` when as soon as the shortcut is created. I've tried calling `Bundle.setClassLoader`, but the error persists.

Is there just a limitation with launchers that support home screen shortcuts?

```
public class Foo implements Parcelable {

    public String title;

    private Foo(Parcel in) {
        title = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(title);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Foo> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Foo>() {

        @Override
        public Foo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Foo(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Foo[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Foo[size];
        }

    };

}
```

---

```
public static void installShortcut(Context context, Foo foo) {
    final Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.setClassLoader(Foo.class.getClassLoader());
    args.putParcelable(EXTRA_FOO, foo);
    final Intent detail = new Intent(context, FooActivity.class);
    detail.putExtras(args);

    final Intent shortcut = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, detail);
    ...
    context.sendBroadcast(shortcut);
}
```

Comment: does Foo is parcelable **with all what it means** (implementing interface is not enough) ?

Comment: @Selvin I updated the OP with `Foo`. It's just a basic `Parcelable` implementation.

Comment: do you have permission .INSTALL_SHORTCUT ?

Comment: @pskink Yes, the function works if I don't specify the `Parcelable`.

Comment: does it also work when you pass any builtin Parcelable?

Comment: @pskink Yes, I can add `Bundle`, for example.

Comment: tried http://www.parcelabler.com/ ?

Comment: @pskink Yes, that's what I use.

Comment: hmm,  strange,  what about passing your Foo objects via Intent to othet activities,  does it fail too?

Comment: @user3959937 just give up with parcelable ... serialize foo object to json and use string param ...